# CoreService filter with SchemaPurpose and Recursive not working

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service, c#

I'm using Core Service API to find all component schemas within a folder recursively.

This is the code.

```cs
OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
filter.Recursive = true;
filter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Schema };
filter.SchemaPurposes = new[] { SchemaPurpose.Component };
IdentifiableObjectData[] results = client.GetList(folderTcm, filter);
```

When I execute this code the results include all kind of schemas, not only those which purpose is `Component`.

I realized that if I set `Recursive` property to `false` or `null` it works fine but of course without finding all schemas down through folders.

I've read the API reference but I can't find any place where it's said that `SchemaPurposes` property can't work with `Recursive` property in the same filter.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I'm trying to retrieve component schemas inside a specific folder recursively excluding other types of schemas like embedded schemas or metadata schemas.

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. There are limitations in which filter options can be combined (in particular for recursive queries on Folder level). IIRC, this is documented somewhere (not sure where, though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rick mentioned in his comment, it might be that what your trying to achieve is not possible within a single call due to limitations of the system. If that is the case, you will have to do the recursion yourself. I suggest you try and dig up whether such limitation is mentioned in the API (.chm file).

I personally have also ran into some limitations with core service filters using recursion (unfortunately I haven't documented it for myself and I can't recall at this moment what it was). Another example, if I recall correctly is, in 2013sp1 TOM.NET combining recursion and schema name to get organizational item items does not work.

Comment: I looked for this in the .chm but didn't found anything. I don't discard it's there, I just didn't find it.

So, yes, I guess you and Rick are right. I should probably implement recursion manually. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, I've had the same problem when trying to recursively search (through Folders) for only Multimedia Components (`filter.ComponentTypes = new[] { ComponentType.Multimedia };`).

Answer (score -1):

**Getting all Components and Schemas in a Publication**

```
RepositoryItemsFilterData filterData = new RepositoryItemsFilterData();
filterData.ItemTypes = new[]
    {
        ItemType.Component,
        ItemType.Schema
    };
filterData.Recursive = true;
XElement resultXml = client.GetListXml(publicationId, filterData);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not useful. I'm not interested in retrieve all components and schemas in a publication, but component schemas (excluding other types of schemas like embedded ones) inside a specific folder instead.